# Why has remix changed so that I cannot enter a string when deploying a contract with bytes16?

Tags: solidity, remix

I am using remix and have been for a while. Since today, I can no longer enter "ABC123" as a variable in a contract when the variable is defined as Bytes16. Instead, I have to enter 0x414243313233 as a value in Remix which is fine but not efficient. Until today it worked... Is there a setting that I inadvertently changed?

The contract looks like:

```
    contract myContract {

        bytes16 public myName;

        function myContract(bytes16 _myName) public {
            myName = _myName;
        } 

        function foo() public view returns (bytes16){
            return fooName;
        }
}
```

I would appreciate any help! Thank-you!

Comment: I think there is not much you can do, that's a feature of the new version of remix.

Comment: Thanks! Any idea why? It is not conducive to fast and efficient programming!